Failed to get request URI: Illegal character in query at index - Spring Webflux
I'm implementing a microservice with Spring WebFlux that exposes some APIs through the following json configuration file:
 [
  {
    "eventConfig": {
      "method": "GET",
      "event": "CREATE",
      "dataEndpoint": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/test",
      "dataIngestionMode": "INSERT_UPDATE",
      "dataIngestionScheduleValue": 2,
      "dataIngestionScheduleUnit": "DAYS",
      "dataIngestionStart": "07:00:00+01:00",
      "dataIngestionStop": "20:00:00+01:00",
      "deltaField": "last_update",
      "deltaFieldOperator": "lt,gt",
      "deltaFieldLowerLimit": "2024-01-01 00:00:00",
      "deltaFieldUpperLimit": "2024-12-31 23:59:59",
      "limit": "100"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "type": "SQL",
      "domain": "TST",
      "service": "APP",
      "entity": "TEST",
      "timestamp": "1695716237608",
      "description": "tabella",
      "term": "GLOSSARIO.TABELLA",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "description": "identificativo",
          "data_type": "integer",
          "constraint": ["PRIMARY_KEY"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "creation_date",
          "description": "data di creazione",
          "data_type": "datetime",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "activation_date",
          "description": "data di attivazione",
          "data_type": "datetime",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "update_date",
          "description": "data di aggiornamento",
          "data_type": "datetime",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "disactivation_date",
          "description": "data di disattivazione",
          "data_type": "datetime",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "owner_title_id",
          "description": "titolo beneficiario",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "owner_fiscal_code",
          "description": "codice fiscale beneficiario",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "SENSIBLE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "companion_title_id",
          "description": "titolo accompagnatore",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "companion_fiscal_code",
          "description": "codice fiscale accompagnatore",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "SENSIBLE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "owner_title_canceled",
          "description": "flag cancellazione titolo beneficiario",
          "data_type": "boolean",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "companion_title_canceled",
          "description": "flag cancellazione titolo accompagnatore",
          "data_type": "boolean",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "arrival_point",
          "description": "stazione di arrivo",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "arrival_coordinates",
          "description": "coordinate stazione di arrivo",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "departure_point",
          "description": "stazione di partenza",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "departure_coordinates",
          "description": "coordinate stazione di partenza",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "ticket_value",
          "description": "valore biglietto",
          "data_type": "double",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "ticket_value_updated",
          "description": "valore biglietto aggiornato",
          "data_type": "double",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "discount_percentage",
          "description": "percentuale di sconto",
          "data_type": "double",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "data_start_val",
          "description": "data inizio validità",
          "data_type": "date",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "data_end_val",
          "description": "data fine validità",
          "data_type": "date",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "ticket_type",
          "description": "tipologia biglietto",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "financial_body",
          "description": "ente",
          "data_type": "string",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "anomaly",
          "description": "flag anomalia",
          "data_type": "boolean",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        },
        {
          "name": "is_active",
          "description": "flag attivazione",
          "data_type": "boolean",
          "constraint": ["NOT_NULL"],
          "masking_type": "NONE",
          "masking_key": "",
          "cleansing": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "service": {
      "query": "SELECT ticket.id, ticket.creation_date, ticket.activation_date, ticket.update_date, ticket.disactivation_date, ticket.owner_title_id, ticket.companion_title_id, registry_owner.fiscal_code AS owner_fiscal_code, registry_companion.fiscal_code AS companion_fiscal_code, ticket.owner_title_canceled, ticket.companion_title_canceled, ticket.arrival_point, ticket.arrival_coordinates, ticket.departure_point, ticket.departure_coordinates, ticket.ticket_value, ticket.ticket_value_updated, ticket.discount_percentage, ticket.data_start_val, ticket.data_end_val, ticket_type.alias AS ticket_type, financial_body.alias AS financial_body, ticket.anomaly, ticket.is_active FROM ticket LEFT JOIN free_instance ON ticket.fk_free_instance = free_instance.id LEFT JOIN ticket_type ON ticket.fk_ticket_type = ticket_type.id LEFT JOIN financial_body ON ticket.fk_financial_body = financial_body.id LEFT JOIN companion ON ticket.fk_companion = companion.id LEFT JOIN applicant_freeinstance ON free_instance.id = applicant_freeinstance.fk_freeinstance LEFT JOIN beneficiary ON beneficiary.id = applicant_freeinstance.fk_beneficiary LEFT JOIN registry AS registry_owner ON registry_owner.id = beneficiary.fk_registry LEFT JOIN registry AS registry_companion ON registry_companion.id = companion.fk_registry;",
      "refer_date": "update_date" 
    }
  }
]

Specifically, the dataEndpoints are read and the APIs are exposed via dynamic code. I attach below the important parts of the code:
@Configuration
public class DynamicRouterConfig {

    private final DynamicHandler dynamicHandler;

    public DynamicRouterConfig(DynamicHandler dynamicHandler) {
        this.dynamicHandler = dynamicHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route() {
        return RouterFunctions.route(
                RequestPredicates.path("/api/v1/{identifier}"), dynamicHandler::handleRequest);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigLoader {

    private static final String JSON_PATH = "static/config.json";

    @Bean
    public List<Config> loadConfigs() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.readValue(new ClassPathResource(JSON_PATH).getInputStream(),
                        new TypeReference<List<Config>>() {});

    }
}

@Component
public class DynamicHandler {

    private final List<Config> configs;
    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    private DataService dataService;

    public DynamicHandler(List<Config> configs, WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.configs = configs;
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
    }

    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        // Recupera l'identificatore decodificato dagli attributi o usa l'originale
        String identifier = request.pathVariable("identifier");
    
        // Trova il Config appropriato
        Config config = configs.stream()
                .filter(c -> c.getEventConfig().getDataEndpoint().contains(identifier))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    
        if (config == null) {
            return ServerResponse.notFound().build();
        }
    
        return dataService.getDbData(config);
    }
    
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    private final List<Config> configs;
    private final FieldValidatorService fieldValidatorService;

    @Autowired
    public AppConfig(List<Config> configs, FieldValidatorService fieldValidatorService) {
        this.configs = configs;
        this.fieldValidatorService = fieldValidatorService;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void validateFieldsOnStartup() {
        // Eseguiamo la validazione dei campi
        fieldValidatorService.validateFields(configs);
    }
}

validateFields is simply a field validator.
I should evolve it by managing params queries of the following type, which, not being encoded, produce Illegal Characters errors:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/test?q={"domain": "TST","service": "APP","entity": "TEST","timestamp": "1695716237608","$cutField": {"lt": "2024-01-01 00:00:00","gt": "2024-12-31 23:59:59"}}&fields=id,valore&limit=100&offset=0

Is there a way to handle spring boot side encoding on all incoming requests? I tried with Filters but I can't even debug the code because it breaks first.
